# Getting sql result as Array

Tags: mysql, sql

Is it possible in MySQL to query from a database and get the result as Array?

### **QUERY**

```
SELECT foo.name,
(
   SELECT data 
   FROM bar 
   WHERE id=foo.userid
) data  
FROM table1 foo;
```

### **Expected Output**

```
+---------+------------------------+
| name    |  data                  |
+=========+========================+
| john    |  ['one','two','three'] |
| martha  |  ['one','five','nine'] |
+---------+------------------------+
```

thanks!

Comment: One array, or an array per row? What should the array look like? The output you specify doesn't make that clear.

Comment: possible duplicate of [SQL Results as PHP Array](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6524116/sql-results-as-php-array)

Comment: I believe this is out of the scope of a classic relational DBMS, research for ORM (Object Relational Mapping) frameworks (e.g., Hibernate), they should help you with this task.

Comment: no, it must be pure sql, no php involve

Comment: Array representation is different in some languages. You need to specify your need exactly to get help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [GROUP_CONCAT](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat)

```
SELECT foo.name,(SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(data SEPARATOR ',') 
                   FROM bar 
                  WHERE id=foo.userid
               GROUP BY data) AS data 
  FROM table1 foo;
```